# Where should i place my index page in angular

Tags: angular

I have an index page in angular which contains header (navbar) and body (details about website). Now i am confused where should i place my index page so that on clicking any link in navbar whole page changes to new component view

Answer (score 0):

Where you place your index page doesn't matter. What you have to do is create routes for all the navigatable pages. And don't forget to make the header a component of its own.

You can check the [Angular style guide](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide) for reference

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your answer. The problem is. I have created an index page and put it in app.component.html and put router-outlet after the html so whenver i am performing routing the new component is loading in router-outlet but it is coming below the index page. I want the page where there is only new component and no other view.

Comment: The app.component.html is the root component of your app and anything there will be persistent across your app. I think you should consider making your index page an independent component. If that doesn't help maybe you could update your question with your current code.

Comment: I think i got it now. Thank you